# Are there any major American cities that regularly experiences significant snow accumulation that do not provide snow removal services?

Tags: united-states, local-government

Are there any major American cities that regularly experiences significant snow accumulation that do not provide or organize snow removal services as a communal service by the city authority for its citizens and leaves the organization entirely or to a large degree up to them? If so how is snow removal handled in those communities?

(I came across this question in an online debate and although some communal services are not fully or partially provided in certain cities, I haven't come across a mention of this particular service. Of course, this does not include simply outsourcing the service to private companies.)

Comment: What are your metrics for major American City?

Comment: Fair question, I'd go with 500k+ inhabitants.

Comment: Given that a city would be shut down if snow wasn't removed, I can't imagine how any city of that size would have gotten to that size without a stable infrastructure which would include snow removal.

Comment: Also if something is left "up to a city to organize themselves" isn't that "communal"?

Comment: 'Citizens'/inhabitants, not city, blip. What I am looking for is when these particular services are not organized by the city authority. One typical example would be firefighters, which are frequently voluntary and not necessarily organized by the city authority. I'll expand the question to see if something comes up...

Comment: There's always the possibility that there are cities for whom snow doesn't generally fall heavily enough to settle, but where it still falls. Where I live, in the UK, we get maybe a couple days a year where snow settles, but most often it's too light for that.

Comment: The closest account i can find is a town, 100k, that turned over the majority of municipal functions to a private LLC, to include snow removal. Similarly, Chicago and other large cities have tried to privatize side street snow removal.

Comment: Which town is it?

Comment: @DrunkCynic that is not that unusual here, but to all effects the services are still responsability of the city government (which happens to provide them through a company). The city retains the right to check the service levels, switch to another provider if the service is not being provided as expected, etc... so it would not fit the OP definition.

Comment: So, outsourcing to private entities is quite common...garbage disposal being a good example. But it's still financed and monitored by the municipality. As for volunteer firefighting...same thing...though they are volunteers, they are still under the purview (at least in the US) of the local municipality (which, again in the US, would typically be a county level government rather than city...)

Comment: Er, what SJuan76 just said! :) So, I guess we're asking for more clarification here. Are you asking for examples of a public service that is normally under the control (on some level) of the local government that's being handled *entirely* by private entities...including funding, oversight, regulation, and coordination? If so, I could think of maybe some non-critical service examples...like a library or park maintenance, but when we're talking critical infrastructure such as transportation, I can't think of any example off hand.

Comment: Yes, it would be something entirely handled by private entities... (or at least largely, I'm starting to compromise here).

Comment: @PeterS. Centennial, Colorado. I can't cite an example where the city exercises zero control over municipal services, which is why I have filed an answer. However, I also haven't stated No, because I'm opposed to proving a negative.

Comment: @PeterS. define 'handled'. As stated, lots of services are *outsourced* to private companies...but the government is the one hiring them. Is that what you are looking for? Or are you looking for an example where the city simply doesn't want to have anything to do with road maintenance, so people figure it out on their own?

Comment: @blip: no, I am not looking for outsourcing. And yes, I am looking for an example where the city simply doesn't want to have anything to do with road maintenance, so people figure it out on their own.

Comment: Thanks, @DrunkCynic! It is not 'the' answer, but a good pointer nonetheless.

Comment: That clarifies things nicely. Thanks for that. Alas, I can't think of any example...nor can I even fathom how that would possibly work with something like snow plowing. :) *Maybe* Detroit would be something to look into? Detroit essentially went bankrupt and lost most of it's population forcing people to fend for themselves in some ways.

Comment: Good pointer, although Detroit has also its snow removal policy. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not an identifiable major city in these United States where the government has chosen to neglect municipal concerns in general, or specifically snow removal. At the minimum, the contract the provision of this services to private companies.

It is doubtful that the voting public would elect, or abide, a government that neglected these expected municipal duties; this is why local governments exist.

On the smaller level, towns with a very low population may not be able to independently support these services, but they would likely choose to band with other towns nearby, or rely upon the county government to provide services to their populace.